# gwt plugin for playframework can not handle the module dependencies

Tags: gwt, module, dependencies, playframework

I have play-framework application that uses one module which I've created by **play new-module** and then added it to the **dependencies.yml** to my app.

I've tested my module with **play deps**, **play mymodule:hello** from the app flolder - everything ok.

[myapplication ---uses---> mymodule]

But when I try to compile that module by **play gwt2:compile** I have an error that application can not find/resolve classes from **mymodule**.

So why gwt can not compile my application if module is already resolved in the application?

P.S.
 I use **gwt2-1.7** plugin and the application works well if I don't use any modules for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by fixing the **gwt2-play** plugin code. So added one line of code to the file devmode.py:

```
cp.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(application_path, 'lib/gwt-user.jar')))
cp.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(gwt2_module_dir, 'app')))
cp.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(gwt2_module_dir, 'hack')))
cp.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(application_path, 'app')))
#added by me
cp.append(app.readConf('gwt2.additional_classpath_entry'))
```

This enables us to specify additional classpath entries in application.conf. Like this:

```
gwt2.additional_classpath_entry = /home/me/projects/myproject/my_modules/my_module/app
```

and, this important: if we want to have dependency like this
**[my_pplication]** ---uses--> **[my_module]**

and if we want to use classes from my_moudle in our gwt-services in the my_application, then we should make my_moudle to be gwt-module by play gwt2:init, play gwt2:create, and we should add these classes to while list like this:

```
package gwt.myproject.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;
import gwt.mymodule.shared.MyModuleClass;

public class WhiteList implements IsSerializable {

    public MyModuleClass mymoduleObject;

}
```